# WCF service with WAS: service cannot convert queue's path name

Tags: wcf, transactions, msmq, wcf-security, was

I got a WCF service listening on a via WAS on a MSMQ which is located on a different server within the same domain.

The setup looks like this:

Server A: Windows Server 2008 hosts the WCF service on IIS.

Server B: Windows Server 2008 (Domain Controller) hosts the private MSMQ (AD Integration).

Furthermore I got also a console client running on Server A which sends message to the service via the MSMQ also using WCF. At the moment the whole setup works and the service processes the messages from the client. The client's security mode is set to `transport` and the service's security mode is set to `none`.

But when I switch the security mode of the service also to `transport` the message are not processed any more. I activated tracing on the service and found out that there seems to be a problem when the service tries to access the MSMQ on the other server. A warning and a error message (see below) can be seen on both security modes `none` and `transport`, but when set to `none` the service seems to ignore the problem and processes the messages never the less.

The error message says:

> An error occurred when converting the
>   'murdock.ltportale.intern\private$\EventSyncService/EventSynchorinzationService.svc'
>   queue path name to the format name:
>   Unrecognized error -1072824300
>   (0xc00e0014). All operations on the
>   queued channel failed. Ensure that the
>   queue address is valid. MSMQ must be
>   installed with Active Directory
>   integration enabled and access to it
>   is available.

I don't think that the address of the MSMQ is wrong as the service can find it with security mode `none`. I'm also quite sure that MSMQ runs with AD integration as this took me 2 days to get it working on my environment.

At the moment I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Running the setup without `transport` security mode is no option for me as my next step would be activating transactions. And I think if transport mode won't work then transaction mode won't work either.

---

**Warning message:**

```
 ...
 <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
     <TraceIdentifier>
         http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueueTransactionalStatusUnknown.aspx
     </TraceIdentifier>
     <Description>
         Cannot detect if the queue is transactional.
     </Description>
     <AppDomain>
         /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/EventSyncService-1-129509714416559522
     </AppDomain>
     <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/StringTraceRecord">                               
         <FormatName> 
              DIRECT=OS:murdock.ltportale.intern\private$\EventSyncService/EventSynchorinzationService.svc
         </FormatName>
     </ExtendedData>
  </TraceRecord>
  ...
```

**Error message:**

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <EventID>131075</EventID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-05-27T12:04:11.5292297Z" />
        <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{f89d797c-3d10-47a3-8dad-1b3200d3b868}" />
        <Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="1764" ThreadID="6" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer>SPS2010-FBE</Computer>
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>
        <TraceData>
            <DataItem>
                <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
                    <TraceIdentifier>
                        http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx
                    </TraceIdentifier>
                    <Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
                    <AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/EventSyncService-1-129509714416559522
                    </AppDomain>
                    <Exception>
                        <ExceptionType>
                            System.ServiceModel.MsmqException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                        </ExceptionType>
                        <Message>
                            An error occurred when converting the 'murdock.ltportale.intern\private$\EventSyncService/EventSynchorinzationService.svc' queue path name to the format name: Unrecognized error -1072824300 (0xc00e0014). All operations on the queued channel failed. Ensure that the queue address is valid. MSMQ must be installed with Active Directory integration enabled and access to it is available.
                        </Message>
                        <StackTrace>
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqFormatName.FromQueuePath(String queuePath)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqVerifier.VerifyReceiver(MsmqReceiveParameters receiveParameters, Uri listenUri)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncodingBindingElement.InternalBuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener&amp;amp; result, Boolean supportContextSession)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener&amp;amp; result)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
                               at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
                               at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
                               at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
                               at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
                               at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
                               at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
                               at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object state)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
                               at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
                               at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
                        </StackTrace>
                        <ExceptionString>
                            System.ServiceModel.MsmqException: An error occurred when converting the 'murdock.ltportale.intern\private$\EventSyncService/EventSynchorinzationService.svc' queue path name to the format name: Unrecognized error -1072824300 (0xc00e0014). All operations on the queued channel failed. Ensure that the queue address is valid. MSMQ must be installed with Active Directory integration enabled and access to it is available.
                        </ExceptionString>
                    </Exception>
                </TraceRecord>
            </DataItem>
        </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

**Configuration client**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <netMsmqBinding>
          <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalNoSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
            <security mode="None"/>
          </binding>
          <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalTransportSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
            <security mode="Transport"/>
          </binding>
        </netMsmqBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
        <endpoint name="EventSyncService.EventSynchorinzationService"
                  address="net.msmq://murdock.ltportale.intern/private/EventSyncService/EventSynchorinzationService.svc"
                  binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalTransportSecurity"
                  contract="SyncService.IEventSynchorinzationService" />
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Configuration service**

```
...
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalNoSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalTransportSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="EventSyncService.EventSynchorinzationService">
        <endpoint 
                  address="net.msmq://murdock.ltportale.intern/private/EventSyncService/EventSynchorinzationService.svc" 
                  binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalNoSecurity" 
                  contract="EventSyncService.IEventSynchorinzationService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\log\log.txt" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Many things could go wrong with WCF and MSMQ.  These artilces helped with a setup similar to yours.

[MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx)

[MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-2.aspx)

[MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-3.aspx)

Comment: Thx, that's the instruction I already followed. I'm stuck in part 2.

Comment: What part did you get to when it started failing?

Comment: Part 2 "Configure the WCF bindings". The binding for the client with 'transport' mode worked but when it was set for the service it stopped processing the messages.

Comment: Have you resolved this?  I am having the same error.

Comment: I'm receiving this error as well, following the same "Play Nice" guide. Has anybody made any progress on this since 2012 ?